# Is Replacement and Repetition the same thing when we say "Permutation with Repetition" or "Permutation with Replacement"?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

According to OALD:

> Repetition: the fact of doing or saying the same thing many times.
>   Replacement: the act of replacing one thing with another.

Thats's in English, how about Math meanings?
As I know, replacement => to distinguish between permutation and combination "importance of order", repetition => means "to pick something up then return it back".
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In combinatorics, it produces the same results. Permutations with repetitions or with replacements just means something can be used more than once, if nothing else is said.

Beware, though, because usually with "replacement" means you replace what you chose every single time. One can ask, however, that something be repeated no more than $k $ times.